# On an integral involving $\zeta(1/2 + i\tau)$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function

Denote by $\zeta$ the Riemann zeta function. Define  $$F_{y}(x)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^{iu}\zeta(1/2 + it + iu)}{u^2  + y^2} \mathrm{d}u.$$

For some fixed real number $t$, is there any $y>0$ such that $F_{y}(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ ?

Comment: What  is $t$ (or $τ$ in the title)?

Comment: @Bullet51, $\tau$ in the title is simply a dummy real variable, and $t$ is some fixed real number.